# Making the emacs cursor into a line

Tags: emacs, emacs23

Hi I have been using Emacs23 for some time now and find it a really cool editor. However I am not happy with the cursor (or point in Emacs lingo) being a ' little black box'. I want it to be a nice thin straight line just the way it is in gedit or notepad. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: This question will most likely get closed as belonging on superuser or some such.  It's not really programing related.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Add this to your .emacs file:

```
(setq-default cursor-type 'bar)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have been looking for this for a few weeks(of course no all the time, anyway...), but Google never gave me this post! Probably here was not enough keywords about a flat cursor *(line cursor, vertical cursor, thin cursor, small cursor)*.